# Books in investment banking

Tags: banking, books, investment-strategies

As a complete newbie here, could anyone suggest a good first book on investment banking for me? Without too many equations to befuddle me (although I work with equations all day).

Heres my background:
+PhD in mechanical engineering
+Masters in mechanical engineering
+Bachelors in mechanical engineering

+Research focuses on non-linear partial differential equations and fluid flow.

Thanks!

Comment: Investment _banking_ is something that big banks like Citibank or Wells Fargo do along with their _retail_ banking business like offering checking accounts and credit cards and the like. If you really want to find out about investment banking, then this question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Note date on the question.i suspect our scope was not so well defined at that time.

Comment: @keshlam It doesn't matter at all whether the scope of money.SE was well-defined in 2012 or not. I suspect that the OP was trying to learn about _investments_ and not investment banking, or at least that is how I interpret his desires based on the answer that he/she accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one book?!

Look for Benjamin Grahams' ***The Intelligent Investor***.

He is cited as one of Warren Buffetts greatest influences, and he seems a fairly successful guy!

Comment: Isn't Graham's book a bit outdated? original version 1965? especially now that with the internet everything changed a little, are there some 'modern classics' or more contemporary introductions? Actually I'm trying 'investment banking for dummies', I'll post an update how i like it!

Comment: The lessons are simple and bely the strength and longevity of the underlying concepts. I think it's still relevant. There's a good reason it's lasted for so long as a important book on the field.